# How to redirect if a JWTException occured

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

How to redirect my laravel webpage to `login` route if I got a message `A token is required` from `JWTException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the token using a middleware:

```
class CheckTokenMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check token here.
        if (!checkToken($request->token)) {
            return redirect('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```